# Can a single Sync Adapter be used for multiple Database Tables?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-contentprovider, android-syncadapter

I need to send bulk of data to my database on server from Android app, and need to sync it periodically. I went through Sync Adapters sample code on [Android Developer's website](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html), but couldn't get the concept and usage.

I need help regarding:

1. how it can be used for server database interaction?
2. can a single Sync adapter be used to synchronize data in multiple tables, at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I start working few days ago on `SyncAdapter`, `SyncService`, I can answer to your second question by YES you can sync multiple tables through a `ContentProvider` implementation.

Your first question has a large scope that I think it will take time to cover. In your `onPermformSync`, you could make HTTP request (PUT / GET etc.) to your server to synchronize local and server information.

I hope my light knowledge on the subject will be helpful !

Comment: Thanks for answering, could you help me with a code sample for the same? That would be great!

Comment: You can read this great article which help me a lot : http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter/

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped :) Very nice tutorial.

Comment: Can you please tell me, how can sync multiple database tables with a single sync adapter?

Comment: Well, in my project, I use a content provider (which is the interface between my multiple SQLite tables). From my `onPerformSync` I call content provider method (`query`, `insert`, `delete`, `update`). These methods use URI to know which table to access.
But you can bypass the content provider (until I suggest you to use it because it brings structure in your application, see http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-writing-your-own-content-provider/)